# ¿Como pasar informacion de jtable a otro jpanel?

Tags: java

pues mi duda es la siguiente.
Tengo un JFrame donde cargo una determinada consulta a mi base de datos y la muestro en un JTable. La cuestion es si uno de esos elementos lo quiero modificar en otro JPanel, osea pinchando sobre la fila y con un boton m llevo esos campos a otro JPanel ¿Cómo guardo esa información para pasarla de panel a panel?  Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Depende de la implementación de *TableModel*.